# How can you prove that $1.05^{50} < 100$ without a calculator?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, number-comparison

Is there a way to prove that $1.05^{50} < 100$ without a calculator?

I have tried this...

$$1.05^{50}<10^2$$
$$(\frac{105}{100})^{50}<10^2$$
$$(\frac{21}{20})^{50}<10^2$$
$$\frac{21^{50}}{20^{50}}<10^2$$
$$\frac{21^{50}}{2^{50}*10^{50}}<10^2$$
$$\frac{21^{50}}{2^{50}}<10^{52}$$
$$10.5^{50}<10^{52}$$

...but I don't know where to go. Can someone assist me (alternate methods are fine)?

**EDIT:**
 Can anyone help me prove that $2^{1000}<10^{302}$ without a calculator?

Comment: It's not particularly close to $100$...very crude estimates will suffice.  Try starting with $1.05^4<\sqrt 2$, say.

Comment: Since $\log(1.05)\le\frac1{20}$ and $e\lt4$, we know that $(1.05)^{50}\le e^{50/20}\le4^{5/2}=32$.

Comment: Trancelocation solution is the most elementary.

Comment: @Anonymous I've added a solution to your second question in my accepted answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

$$
1.05^{50} = \left(1+\frac{5}{100}\right)^{50}
= \sqrt{\left(1+\frac{5}{100}\right)^{100}}
< \sqrt{e^5} = \sqrt{e}^5 < 2^5 = 32
$$

Edit: for you second inequality, $2^{1000}<10^{302}$ is equivalent to $(2^{10})^{100}<10^2(10^3)^{100}$, which is equivalent to
$$
\left(\frac{2^{10}}{10^3}\right)^{100} = \left(1+\frac{24}{1000}\right)^{100} < 100.
$$
From $a\log(1+t)\leq at$ for $a>0$ we deduce $(1+t)^a\leq e^{at}$. Therefore
$$
\left(1+\frac{24}{1000}\right)^{100} < e^{\frac{24}{1000}\cdot100}
<e^{5/2} < 32 < 100.
$$

---

*Addendum.* What is trickier, is proving that $2^{1000}>10^{301}$. Can you do that?

Here is how I go about it. Maybe someone else can find a simpler derivation.

Define
$$
\exp_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!} < \exp(x) .
$$

We want $\left(\frac{2^{10}}{10^3}\right)^{100}>10$. From $(1-t)^a\leq e^{-at}$ you deduce $\left(\frac1{1-t}\right)^a\geq e^{at}$. So
$$
\begin{split}
\left(\frac{2^{10}}{10^3}\right)^{100}
&= \left(\frac{1024}{1000}\right)^{100}
= \left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{24}{1024}}\right)^{100}
\geq e^{100\cdot\frac{24}{1024}} = e^{75/32} \\
&= e^{2+11/32} > e^{2+11/33}
= \exp(2)\exp(1/3) > \exp_5(2)\exp_2(1/3) \\
&= \left(1+2+2+\frac43+\frac23+\frac4{15}\right)\left(1+\frac13+\frac1{18}\right) \\
&= \frac{109}{15} \cdot \frac{25}{18} = \frac{545}{54} > 10.
\end{split}
$$

Comment: How do you know the middle term is $<\sqrt{e^{5}}$?

Comment: Definition of $e^x$.

Comment: Because $(1+x/n)^n$ is increasing to $e^x$

Comment: Does anyone have a simpler method?

Comment: @Anonymous I posted another one

Comment: You could just add that as an edit rather than post a new one.

Comment: @KM101 Yeah I don't know how things work in this case. I mean, it's a completely independent methd

Comment: I think posting a second answer is perfectly justified in this case.

Comment: Well, now that I look again, in both cases I reach the estimate $<e^{5/2}$, and then just conclude differently.

Comment: I have edited the question with a follow-up. Please assist me.

Answer (score 7):

$\log(1.05^{50}) = 50\log(1.05) < 50·0.05 = 2.5 < 3$. Then
$1.05^{50} < e^3 < 3^3 = 27$.

Comment: Just for clarity, this uses the fact that $\log(1+x)<x$ for all $x>0$ (this can be proven using relatively elementary methods [e.g., first-year calculus]).

Comment: Yeah of course. It was a common trick back then when we still used logarithm tables...

Comment: @Clayton No worries, I was just joking! It was just to say that indeed it is a basic fact. And I'm not old enough to have used logarithm tables! :D

Comment: I have edited the question with a follow-up. Please assist me.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an elementary way using GM-HM.

First note

- $1.05^{50} < 100 \Leftrightarrow \boxed{1.05 < \sqrt[50]{100}}$

$$\color{blue}{\sqrt[50]{100}} = \sqrt[50]{2^2\cdot 5^2 \cdot 1^{46}} \color{blue}{\stackrel{\mbox{GM-HM}}{>}}\frac{50}{\frac{2}{2}+\frac{2}{5}+46}=\frac{250}{237}=1+\frac{13}{237}> \color{blue}{1.05}$$

Comment: This is most elementary solution! +1

Answer (score 2):

Use
$$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n<\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+1}\leq4,$$
because $\{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+1}\}$ is a decreasing sequence,
we have
$$1.05^{50}=\left(\left(1+\frac1{20}\right)^{20}\right)^{\frac52}
<4^{\frac52}=2^5=32<100.$$

Answer (score 1):

$(1+x)^r\leq e^{rx}$. If $x=0.05$ and $r=50$, then $rx=50\times \frac{5}{100}=\frac{250}{100}=2.5$. Therefore $(1.05)^{50}\leq e^{2.5}$. Since $2\lt e\lt 3$, we have $2^{2.5}\lt e^{2.5}\lt 3^{2.5}$. We also have $3^{2.5}\lt 3^3$, and since $3^3=27$, we may say that $(1.05)^{50}\lt 27\lt 100$, proving the claim. No calculators required!

Answer (score 0):

We have to prove $\left(\frac{21}{20}\right)^{50} < 100$, which simplifies to:
$$
3^{50}7^{50} < 2^{102}5^{52}.
$$

We have $3^5 = 243 < 256 = 2^8$, and $7^2 = 49 < 50 = 2\cdot5^2$, therefore:
$$
3^{50}7^{50} = (3^5)^{10}(7^2)^{25} < (2^8)^{10}(2\cdot5^2)^{25} = 2^{105}5^{50} = 2^{102}\cdot8\cdot5^{50} < 2^{102}5^{52}.
$$

---

(I didn't notice that a second, unrelated question had been tacked onto the end - naughty, that!)

From
\begin{equation}
\tag{$*$}\label{ineq:crux}
2^{10} = 1024 < 1025 = 5^2\cdot41,
\end{equation}
we get
$$
\frac{2^{30}}{5^6} = \left(\frac{2^{10}}{5^2}\right)^3< 41^3 = 68921 < 69000 = 69\cdot2^3\cdot5^3,
$$
and from this, together with \eqref{ineq:crux} again, we get
$$
\frac{2^{37}}{5^{11}} = \left(\frac{2^{27}}{5^{9}}\right)\left(\frac{2^{10}}{5^{2}}\right) < 69\cdot41 = 2829 < 3125 = 5^5,
$$
whence
$$
2^{37} < 5^{16}.
$$
One more slog, and we're done:
\begin{gather*}
\left(2^{349}\right)^{16} = 2^{5584} < 2^{5587} = \left(2^{37}\right)^{151} < \left(5^{16}\right)^{151} = \left(5^{151}\right)^{16}, \\
\therefore\ 2^{1000} = 2^{302}\left(2^{349}\right)^2 < 2^{302}\left(5^{151}\right)^2 = 2^{302}5^{302} = 10^{302}.
\end{gather*}

Answer (score 0):

I'll use this CW answer to gather together some deductions from the
power series expansion
$$
\frac12\log\frac{1+x}{1-x} = x+\frac{x^3}3+\frac{x^5}5+\cdots.
$$
This can be truncated to give lower bounds, and its remainder can be
replaced by a geometric series with common ratio $x^2$ to give upper
bounds.

---

Taking the first question first:
\begin{multline*}
50\log\frac{21}{20} =
100\cdot\frac12\log\frac{1+\tfrac1{41}}{1-\tfrac1{41}} <
100\cdot\frac1{41}\left(1-\frac1{41^2}\right)^{-1} \\ =
\frac{100\cdot41}{41^2-1} = \frac{100\cdot41}{40\cdot42} =
\frac{205}{84} < \frac52,
\end{multline*}
whence
$$
\left(\frac{21}{20}\right)^{50} < e^{5/2} < 3^{5/2} = \sqrt{243} <
\sqrt{256} = 16 < 100. \quad \square
$$

---

It doesn't take much more work to get a sharper upper bound:
$$
\left(\frac{21}{20}\right)^{50} < 12.
$$
Proof:
$$
50\log\frac{21}{20} < \frac{205}{84} < \frac{49}{20} < \log{12}.
$$
The penultimate inequality follows from
$$
20\cdot205 = 4100 < 4116 = 4200 - 84 = 50\cdot84 - 84 = 49\cdot84.
$$
The final inequality is proved as follows:
\begin{gather*}
\log3 = 2\cdot\frac12\log\frac{1+\tfrac12}{1-\tfrac12} >
2\left(\frac12 + \frac1{3\cdot2^3}\right) = \frac{13}{12}; \\
\log2 = 2\cdot\frac12\log\frac{1+\tfrac13}{1-\tfrac13} >
2\left(\frac13 + \frac1{3^4}\right) = \frac{56}{81}; \\
\log{12} = \log3 + 2\log2 > \frac{13}{12} + \frac{112}{81} =
\frac{351+448}{324} = \frac{799}{324} > \frac{800}{325} =
\frac{32}{13} > \frac{49}{20},
\end{gather*}
because $20\cdot32 = 640 > 637 = 650-13 = 50\cdot13-13 = 49\cdot13.
\quad \square$

---

An answer to the OP's second question can be deduced from the
inequality in the first question.  As @Federico notes in his answer,
the second question reduces to
$$
\left(\frac{2^{10}}{10^3}\right)^{100} < 100.
$$
Therefore, it is enough to prove
$$
\left(\frac{2^{10}}{10^3}\right)^2 = \left(1 + \frac3{125}\right)^2
< 1 + \frac1{20} = \frac{21}{20};
$$
and the central inequality does hold, because
$$
\frac1{20} - \left(\frac6{125} + \frac9{125^2}\right) =
\left(\frac6{120} - \frac6{125}\right) - \frac9{125^2} =
\frac1{125}\left(\frac14 - \frac9{125}\right) > 0.
\quad \square
$$
(With hindsight, it would have been simpler just to write
$1.024^2 = 1.048576 < 1.05$!)

---

Alternatively, we can answer the second question directly, using the
same power series again:
\begin{multline*}
100\log\frac{2^{10}}{10^3} = 100\log\left(1+\frac6{250}\right) =
200\cdot\frac12\log\frac{1+\tfrac3{253}}{1-\tfrac3{253}} \\
< \frac{600}{253}\left(1-\left(\frac3{253}\right)^2\right)^{-1}\!\!
= \frac{600\cdot253}{253^2-3^2} = \frac{600\cdot253}{250\cdot256} =
\frac{3\cdot253}{5\cdot64} = \frac{759}{320} < \frac52,
\end{multline*}
whence, exactly as with the first question,
$$
\left(\frac{2^{10}}{10^3}\right)^{100} < e^{5/2} < 3^{5/2} =
\sqrt{243} < \sqrt{256} = 16. \quad \square
$$

---

Also in his answer, @Federico poses (and solves) the problem of
proving
$$
\left(\frac{2^{10}}{10^3}\right)^{100} > 10.
$$
We can prove this by using the power series again.  To begin with,
$$
100\log\frac{2^{10}}{10^3} = 100\log\left(1+\frac6{250}\right) =
200\cdot\frac12\log\frac{1+\tfrac3{253}}{1-\tfrac3{253}} >
\frac{600}{253} > \frac73.
$$

@Federico gives a short and clear proof that $e^{7/3} > 10$ by using
the power series for $e^x,$ and this is probably to be preferred;
but I'll give another proof, using the same power series I've been
using throughout. (There are several other reasonable-looking ways
to use the same power series to prove the result, and I make no claim
that this is the neatest.)
$$
\log3 = 2\cdot\frac12\log\frac{1+\tfrac12}{1-\tfrac12} <
2\left(\frac12 + \frac1{3\cdot2^3}\left(
1-\frac1{2^2}\right)^{-1}\right) = 2\left(\frac12+\frac1{18}\right)
= \frac{10}9;
$$
\begin{multline*}
\log\frac{10}9 = 2\log\frac{1+\tfrac1{19}}{1-\tfrac1{19}} <
2\left(\frac1{19} + \frac1{3\cdot{19}^3}\left(
1-\frac1{{19}^2}\right)^{-1}\right) = \\
2\left(\frac1{19} + \frac1{3\cdot19\cdot(19^2-1)}\right) =
2\left(\frac1{19} + \frac1{3\cdot18\cdot19\cdot20}\right) <
2\left(\frac1{19} + \frac1{18\cdot19}\right) = \frac19;
\end{multline*}
$$
\log{10} = 2\log3 + \log\frac{10}9 < \frac{20}9 + \frac19 = \frac73.
\quad \square
$$

---

That will have to be enough for today, but it would be fun to give
similar proofs of the two middle inequalities here:
$$
10 < \left(\frac{2^{10}}{10^3}\right)^{100}\!\! < 11 <
\left(\frac{21}{20}\right)^{50}\! < 12,
$$
and as this is a CW answer, anyone should feel free to append
such proofs.

Answer (score -1):

By writing 1.05 as (1 + 0.05) and expanding by using binomial Theorem, you can clearly see that in all terms there is positive power in 0.05 ( except the first one) which is making it smaller. So it can never be greater than 100 or even leave 100 it can never be greater than 50.

Comment: Can you be more specific? You say that it does not go above 100, which is true, but by the same vague argument you could just say that it does not go above 10, which is false. I think you need to be quantitative with the estimates